# tensorflow predict on many images

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained a tensorflow model using the retrain image-retraining example: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html

Now I want to use it to predict on many images, I've modified this python [script](https://github.com/eldor4do/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/retraining-example.py) to run on many images:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import glob
import os
modelFullPath = 'output_graph.pb'


def create_graph():
    """Creates a graph from saved GraphDef file and returns a saver."""
    # Creates graph from saved graph_def.pb.                                                                                                                                                                       
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(modelFullPath, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    imagePath = 'MYFOLDERWITHIMAGES/*.jpg'
    testimages=glob.glob(imagePath)

    ## init numpy array to hold all predictions                                                                                                                                                                    
    all_predictions = np.zeros(shape=(len(testimages),121)) ## 121 categories                                                                                                                                      


    # Creates graph from saved GraphDef.                                                                                                                                                                           
    create_graph()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
        for i in range(len(testimages)):
            image_data1 = tf.gfile.FastGFile(testimages[i], 'rb').read()
            predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor,
                                   {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data1})
            all_predictions[i,:] = np.squeeze(predictions)
            if i % 100 == 0:
              print(str(i) +' of a total of '+ str(len(testimages)))
```

but even running on my gpu it is rather slow (aprox. 25 sec per 500 images).
How can I speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

The standard ways of speeding up tensorflow are probably a good idea here. For example, using input queues can help you keep your GPU busy, as described in [the reading data section of the tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/reading_data/index.html). Also to improve GPU utilization you want to use a larger batch size than predicting one image at a time.

Comment: Hi Alexandre, can you please provide an example on how to "use a larger batch for prediction?"